# Downloading target link html in a text file (Beautiful Soup - Python3)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am completely new to python and studying Web crawling.

I am trying to download individual target link in a text page.
So far, I succeeded to extract all the target URLs I need, but have no idea on how to download all target HTML texts in a text file.

Can someone give me a general idea.

```
url = ""
r  = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
link1 = soup2.find_all('a', href=re.compile("drupal_lists"))
for t in link1:
    print(t.attrs['href'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your for loop access the link urls using the requests lib and write the contents to a file. Something like:

```
link_data = requests.get(t.attrs['href']).text
with open('file_to_write.out', 'w') as f:
  f.write(link_data)
```

You may want to change the filename for each link.

Comment: I added this for statement, but it doesnt work. it just shows one target link. what is wrong here? for t in link1:
    link_data = requests.get(t.attrs['href']).text
    with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(link_data)